# how to add search box in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I draw many lines in matplotlib. These lines represent the roads in the map. Since the map is very large, I want to find lane by laneid.

So how to implement this function in matplotlib? Similar to the input address in the current map to show certain areas

Below is the map draw by matplotlib.
[image]

Comment: That’s a very amorphous question. What are you having trouble with, specifically?

Comment: How do I enter laneid and zoom in to the current box in perspective, and how do I display the input box on matplotlib